# SSL module not available when installing python modules

Tags: python, installation, ss

I've been trying to install python modules from cmd,
but I'm getting the following error:

> There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:
>
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

If anyone could help that would be great!

---

**Image of the error:**
[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on macOS. I guess my problem is because my python@2 was installed by homebrew.

Searched and tried many ways. Here is what works for me, and for your reference if you also happen to use homebrew on macOS.

### I. Use default python on macOS

Step1. brew uninstall python@2

Step2. sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip

Step3. cd `HOMBREW_BIN_PATH`

Step4. ln -sf /usr/bin/python python

Step5. ln -sf /usr/local/bin/pip pip

Then you can use pip as usual.

### II. A workaround with non-https source instead

Refers to: https://blog.51cto.com/tenderrain/1956752

Suppose here we use non-https source of `mirrors.aliyun.com`, and want to install `six`

**Method1. Directly by CLI**

pip install -i http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple six --trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com

**Method2. Create a ~/.pip/pip.conf**

```
[global]
index-url = http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/

[install]
trusted-host=mirrors.aliyun.com
```

Then use `pip install six` as usual.